# asp directive value different between aspx and aspx.cs

Tags: asp.net, directive

Maybe it's a huge mistake from my side but when i put he following directive in the .aspx file
`<%=Commande.GetOrder(Page).Total; %>`
it returns a value = 0 (which is wrong)

and if i look for the same value in the .aspx.cs i got the real value (409.11)
`decimal d = Commande.GetOrder(Page).Total;`

Obviously i can make an asp:Label and put the Label.Text in the page load to get the real value, but i'm wondering why it doesnt work because it looks like it worked before.
Thanks.

Comment: The semi-colon shouldn't be there, since you're retrieving a value, not just executing a statement - but that would cause a compilation error, not give you a zero. Without seeing the rest of the code, all I can say is the state of your objects must be different during the time that it executes on the page vs. in the code-behind. You'll have to throw a breakpoint on `GetOrder` to watch it execute in both situations, to see what's different.

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon (`;`) is the problem in your embedded code block.

Change this:

```
<%=Commande.GetOrder(Page).Total; %>
```

To this:

```
<%=Commande.GetOrder(Page).Total %>
```